# Search Users by role on WSO2 Identity Server API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to search all users that have a specific role using the WSO2 Identity Server API.

I'm calling GET /scim2/Users?filter=roles+Co+roleName

But I receive the following answers from the API:
Unsupported attribute: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:roles

Does anyone know how to add the attribute role in the filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.4.2.2,
filter should be as follows.

```
GET {{base_url}}/scim2/Users?filter=roles[display co role1]
```

However, WSO2 IS doesn't support multivalued complex attribute filtering.
NOTE: Filtering is an optional operation to be supported by the SCIM service provider

The alternative option is:

1. Get role id from

```
GET {{base_url}}/scim2/Roles?filter=displayName co role1
```

2. Then retrieve the users assigned to the role

```
GET {{base_url}}/scim2/Roles/{{role-id}}?attributes=users
```